# Beginner question: Why is Selenium launching two windows, when instantiated once only?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm trying to separate my program into separate files. First there is Webdriver Manager :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

class DriverManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        # This downloads latest webdriver if needed

    def get_driver(self):
        return(self.driver)

driver_manager = DriverManager() 
# Instantiates the class
```

Second, comes the actual bot

```
from selenium import webdriver
from data.driver_manager import driver_manager

class Crawler (webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver=driver_manager.get_driver):
        super().__init__()
      
    def goto_frontpage(self):
        self.get("stackoverflow.com")
```

Then comes the main method

```
from data.crawler import Crawler


init = Crawler()
init.goto_frontpage()
```

I was trying to build in more methods, such as element finding and the usual stuff, but nothing seems to be happening.

All this does is launch two (for some reason) chrome windows, one of which navigates to provided site, but that's it, find_element methods added later don't work.

I've been trying to restructure the code, but I'm not able to fix it.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You're creating two `webdriver.Chrome` instances: one at  `driver_manager  = DriverManager()`, and one at `init = Crawler()`. Note that you never actually use `DriverManager` from `Crawler`. `Crawler` is just a standalone subclass of `webdriver.Chrome`.